# Random sample in R based on two probabiility vectors

Tags: r, random

Sampling in R is pretty straightforward, but I am stumbling on the following. I want to generate a random sample of one thousand 0's and 1's where each sample unit of 1 has its own probability of selection. The code I am using is as follows:

```
Sample <- sample (0:1, 1000, replace = T, prob = c(data$No, data$Yes))
```

Where `data$No` is the probability vector of the individual not doing action N with `data$Yes` being the probability vector that the individual will do it. Where **No + Yes = 1**

Each of the 1000 individuals has their own unique probability of doing the action.

I want to generate probable outcomes of doing the action based on each individuals unique probability. But R is fighting me every step of the way.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `rbinom`. There are 1000 individuals, each getting one trial (`size = 1`). The probability of success is `data$Yes`

```
rbinom(n = 1000,size = 1,prob = data$Yes)
```

Comment: great answer, worked perfect